# How to memoize custom React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, memoization

```
const useSomeHook = ({number}) => {
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setNewNumber(number + 1)
  }, [number])
}

const SomeComponent = ({number, value, ...restProps}) => {

  useSomeHook({number})


  return <div>{number}</div>
}
```

Let's imagine I have this case. Each time when in `SomeComponent` come some new prop, it will call my `useSomeHook` hook, but I want to prevent it. I want to call it only when the `number` is changed (`memoize` it). In other cases, don't touch it. But I haven't found any solving with this case. Could you help me solve this issue?

Comment: The `useEffect` hook within `useSomeHook` will only be invoked when the dependency `number` changes.

Comment: So I don't see what memoization gives you in this case.

Comment: In this case it will be ok, but imagine that I have some hard logic in this hook, and it invoked each time for example I type something with redux form , and it works horrible

Comment: What you pass in the second argument for `useEffect` will trigger subsequent invocation of the callback you pass in as the first argument. 
To address your ask, you can do two things: 1. Add in-depth equality check as the second param (this requires some work), and/or 2. Add a condition in the callback; ex: `if (obj.a !== obj.b) callback()`

Comment: use `useRef` instead of `useState`

Answer (score 12):

You can not prevent calling hook, this will lead to invariant violation error. Every hook in component should be executed on each render. You should rely on `useEffect` dependencies argument to run conditional code only if value changes.

Answer (score 2):

use `useRef` instead of `useState` to memoize/cache the returned value so that its not recomputed when its used across components, or when there are multiple instances of that component

```js
const useSomeHook = ({number}) => {
  const numberRef = useRef(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    numberRef.current = numberRef.current + 1
  }, [number])
}

const SomeComponent = ({number, value, ...restProps}) => {

  useSomeHook({number})


  return <div>{number}</div>
}
```

it also sounds like you want to use `useMemo` instead of `useEffect`

```js
const useSomeHook = ({number}) => {
  const numberRef = useRef(0)

  cachedValue = useMemo(() => {
    return numberRef.current + 1
  }, [number])
   return cachedValue
}

const SomeComponent = ({number, value, ...restProps}) => {

  const cachedValue = useSomeHook({number})


  return <div>{number}</div>
}
```

Comment: what if our `useSomeHook` is making an api call, it that case `useRef` might not be a good thing to use as well, thoughts ?

Comment: @Prateek Why not? I would argue that using useRef especially when making api calls is even better because you can use it to cache the api call response, otherwise if you use the same hook across multiple components, you would be making multiple api calls