# Can I rerun a hook only if parameters changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

I have a react component that uses some hooks. The component will call hooks with parameters and get a value back.

Is there a way to only execute the hook if the parameter is different from the previous value just like how we can use `React.memo()` on the component itself and avoid rerendering if the props are the same?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/61438672/12036438](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61438672/12036438)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to memoize custom React hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438517/how-to-memoize-custom-react-hook)